# my vendor/craftcms/cms folder delete automatically after every update or install

Tags: craft3, install, installation, updates

I was on version 3.1.22. As usual, I wanted to install the update on Craft CMS 3.1.23.
So I clicked Install and got this error:

> Status: Error

But that was not all ... My complete vendor/craftcms/cms folder has been deleted. The solution to get back to the CP and the frontend, was to manually upload 3.1.22 back to the folder. When I started the update again - same error. In the while, I have manually updated to 3.1.24. However, I can no longer update plugins or install new ones. The CMS folder is deleted every time.

Does anyone have a similar problem or idea how to solve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue yesterday.

When running composer install from my linux (Homestead box), via the command line, a stack of weird errors flew by indicating a "problem with the zip file".

Then craft died. All the vendor/craftcms files were created but empty!

Only way round it, for me, was to run the composer install from windows instead.

Comment: strange… I didn't changed anything in the config file. Could it be that version 3.1.23 has a bug?

Comment: Maybe - or perhaps something weird with the zip file maybe?

Comment: an official answer would be nice. atm I can't update my plugins or install a new one. If I try it craft totally crash.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this locally.

I had to clear my composer cache with `composer clear-cache`. Composer install ran perfectly and all is well with the world.